# foundation javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have some issues that been troubleshooting all week long.  I tried it on bracket IDE and on codepen but I couldn't make the foundation framework to work as it should be like what on there website

for example [this](https://codepen.io/error467/pen/BeqrdY) should work like below link: https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/off-canvas-full-screen.html

```html
<div id="offcanvas-full-screen" class="offcanvas-full-screen" data-off-canvas data-transition="overlap">
  <div class="offcanvas-full-screen-inner">
    <button class="offcanvas-full-screen-close" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="offcanvas-full-screen-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="top-bar-title">
      <strong>Site Title</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
      <button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas-full-screen"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you forgot to initialize foundation.**

just add

```
<script>  
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

And it will work.

Comment: I did..  but still does not work.  For example this slider the handle not even moving..  https://codepen.io/error467/pen/PvyyNw

Comment: util.keyboard.js was missing and the order was not correct. See https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/BeGjpv

Comment: i got it working guys.  Though all the suggestion was right.  I had some js missing and jquery need to be first on the line before all other JS.